# Passing a variable of Linear Layout type to another class - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a variable name scratchLabel of type Linear Layout and I need to access it from another class.

This is the code I've tried but I'm getting a error inside the private constructor Messanger.(this.layout = in.readValue() ).

```
public class Messanger implements Parcelable {

    private LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(layout);

    }
    public Messanger(LinearLayout layout){
        this.layout = layout;
    }
    private Messanger(Parcel in){
        this.layout = in.readValue();

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Messanger> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Messanger>(){

        @Override
        public Messanger createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Messanger(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Messanger[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Messanger[size];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error? Print stacktrace.

Comment: Inside the private constructor (private Messenger) i get - readValue (ClassLoader) in Parcel cannot be applied